# Passing Data in Flutter between pages

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, data-storage, data-sharing

Hey so i stored a dateTime as a variable in one of my app pages and i want to recieve it on another page but am having problems,

This is where I stored my  date time in a variable :

```
import 'package:cycle/pages/homePage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class DatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DatePickerState createState() => _DatePickerState();
}

//Today's Date
DateTime _currentdate = new DateTime.now();

//Storing the date time here
var lastMenusEnd ;

//Using date picker to get last menus
Future<Null> _selectdate(BuildContext context) async{
      final DateTime _seldate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: _currentdate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2020),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100),
        builder: (context,child) {

          return Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
               primaryColor: Colors.pinkAccent[200],
                ),
             child:  SingleChildScrollView(child: child,)
             );

        }
      );
      if(_seldate!=null) {

         lastMenusEnd = _seldate;
         Home(lastmenus: lastMenusEnd); // This is what am using to send it to the home page

      }
  }



class _DatePickerState extends State<DatePicker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              children :  <Widget>[
                 Text(
                   'Hello',
                   textScaleFactor : 1,
                   style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.black,
                     fontFamily: 'Comic',
                     fontSize: 24
                     ),
                   ),
                   Text(
                   'Please insert correct details',
                   textScaleFactor : 1,
                   style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.black,
                     fontFamily: 'Comic',
                     fontSize: 24
                     ),
                   ),
                   Row(
                     children :  <Widget>[
                     Text(
                    'When did your last menustration end ?',
                     textScaleFactor : 1, 
                     style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.black,
                     fontFamily: 'Comic',
                     fontSize: 24
                     ),
                   ),

                     SizedBox(width: 16),

                    IconButton(onPressed: (){
                    _selectdate(context);
                    },icon: Icon(
                    Icons.calendar_today,
                    color: Colors.black,
                   ),
                   ),
                     ]
                   ),

              ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is where I am trying to retrieve the data but i cant get it:

```
    import 'package:cycle/animation/animationReflectly.dart';
import 'package:cycle/model/date.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';




class Home extends StatefulWidget {

DateTime lastmenus;
Home({this.lastmenus});

  @override
 _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();


}




class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

 DateTime lastMenusEnd;

  @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
      lastMenusEnd = widget.lastmenus;
      // Getting the present day
DateTime _currentdate = new DateTime.now();



//Using date picker to get last menus


//Day last menustration ended
//DateTime lastMenusEnd = Home.lastmenus;// use date picker to get the date and store it here



// Adding watch day periods to the last menus date
// So normally am using a set Day span of 28days...
// Cause its meant to range from 21days to 35days...
// So am adding a three day notice alert which is going to be on the 25th day... 
// And also just a 2 day after.. Which will be in light pink box also 

// cycle1
var d25 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 25));//minor alert
var d26 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 26));//minor alert
var d27 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 27));//minor alert
var d28 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 28));//major
var d29 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 29));//major
var d30 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 30));//major
var d31 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 31));//major ....
var d32 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 32));//major
var d33 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 33));//major
var d34 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 34));//minor alert
var d35 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 35));//minor alert
var d36 = lastMenusEnd.add(new Duration(days: 36));//minor alert

//cycle 2 (start 25day count from where major 4 ended)
var dd25 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 25));//minor alert
var dd26 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 26));//minor alert
var dd27 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 27));//minor alert
var dd28 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 28));//major
var dd29 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 29));//major
var dd30 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 30));//major
var dd31 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 31));//major ....
var dd32 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 32));//major
var dd33 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 33));//major
var dd34 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 34));//minor alert
var dd35 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 35));//minor alert
var dd36 = d31.add(new Duration(days: 36));//minor alert

//cycle 3 (start 25day count from where major ended)
var ddd25 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 25));//minor alert
var ddd26 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 26));//minor alert
var ddd27 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 27));//minor alert
var ddd28 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 28));//major
var ddd29 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 29));//major
var ddd30 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 30));//major
var ddd31 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 31));//major ....
var ddd32 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 32));//major
var ddd33 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 33));//major
var ddd34 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 34));//minor alert
var ddd35 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 35));//minor alert
var ddd36 = dd31.add(new Duration(days: 36));//minor alert

//cycle 4 (start 25day count from where major ended)
var dddd25 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 25));//minor alert
var dddd26 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 26));//minor alert
var dddd27 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 27));//minor alert
var dddd28 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 28));//major
var dddd29 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 29));//major
var dddd30 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 30));//major
var dddd31 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 31));//major ....
var dddd32 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 32));//major
var dddd33 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 33));//major
var dddd34 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 34));//minor alert
var dddd35 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 35));//minor alert
var dddd36 = ddd31.add(new Duration(days: 36));//minor alert


var formattedToday = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_currentdate);

//Converting cycle 1 to a readable format

var d25F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d25);
var d26F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d26);
var d27F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d27);
var d28F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d28);
var d29F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d29);
var d30F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d30);
var d31F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d31);
var d32F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d32);
var d33F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d33);
var d34F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d34);
var d35F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d35);
var d36F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(d36);

//Converting cycle 2 to a readable format

var dd25F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd25);
var dd26F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd26);
var dd27F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd27);
var dd28F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd28);
var dd29F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd29);
var dd30F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd30);
var dd31F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd31);
var dd32F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd32);
var dd33F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd33);
var dd34F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd34);
var dd35F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd35);
var dd36F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dd36);

//Converting cycle 3 to a readable format

var ddd25F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd25);
var ddd26F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd26);
var ddd27F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd27);
var ddd28F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd28);
var ddd29F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd29);
var ddd30F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd30);
var ddd31F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd31);
var ddd32F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd32);
var ddd33F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd33);
var ddd34F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd34);
var ddd35F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd35);
var ddd36F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(ddd36);

//Converting cycle 4 to a readable format

var dddd25F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd25);
var dddd26F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd26);
var dddd27F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd27);
var dddd28F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd28);
var dddd29F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd29);
var dddd30F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd30);
var dddd31F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd31);
var dddd32F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd32);
var dddd33F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd33);
var dddd34F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd34);
var dddd35F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd35);
var dddd36F = new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dddd36);








//Placing the newly formatted dates into the list for the List Tile
//Am also placing different colors on each list item
//Am also add a delay for the delayed Animation so it looks fresher
List<DateArrange> dates = [
  DateArrange(dateName: formattedToday, color: Colors.white, delay: 3000),
  // Cycle 1

   DateArrange(dateName: d25F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 3100),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: d26F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 3200),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: d27F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 3300),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: d28F, color: Colors.red, delay: 3400),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: d29F, color: Colors.red, delay: 3500),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: d30F, color: Colors.red, delay: 3600),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: d31F, color: Colors.red, delay: 3700),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: d32F, color: Colors.red, delay: 3800),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: d33F, color: Colors.red, delay: 3900),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: d34F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 4000),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: d35F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 4100),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: d36F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 4200),//minor

   // Cycle 2

   DateArrange(dateName: dd25F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 4300),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dd26F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 4400),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dd27F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 4500),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dd28F, color: Colors.red, delay: 4600),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dd29F, color: Colors.red, delay: 4700),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dd30F, color: Colors.red, delay: 4800),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dd31F, color: Colors.red, delay: 4900),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dd32F, color: Colors.red, delay: 5000),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dd33F, color: Colors.red, delay: 5100),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dd34F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 5200),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dd35F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 5300),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dd36F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 5400),//minor

    // Cycle 3

   DateArrange(dateName: ddd25F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 5500),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd26F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 5600),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd27F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 5700),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd28F, color: Colors.red, delay: 5800),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd29F, color: Colors.red, delay: 5900),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd30F, color: Colors.red, delay: 6000),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd31F, color: Colors.red, delay: 6100),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd32F, color: Colors.red, delay: 6200),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd33F, color: Colors.red, delay: 6300),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd34F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 6400),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd35F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 6500),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: ddd36F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 6600),//minor

   // Cycle 4

   DateArrange(dateName: dddd25F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 6700),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd26F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 6800),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd27F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 6900),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd28F, color: Colors.red, delay: 7100),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd29F, color: Colors.red, delay: 7200),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd30F, color: Colors.red, delay: 7300),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd31F, color: Colors.red, delay: 7400),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd32F, color: Colors.red, delay: 7500),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd33F, color: Colors.red, delay: 7600),//major
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd34F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 7700),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd35F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 7800),//minor
   DateArrange(dateName: dddd36F, color: Colors.pinkAccent[100], delay: 7900),//minor

];

  }

  final int delayedAmount = 500;
  //final AuthService _auth = AuthService();





  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
            appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
             IconButton(onPressed: (){
                 _selectdate(context);
             },icon: Icon(
               Icons.calendar_today,
               color: Colors.black,
               ),)
        ],
      ),
      body:  SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB( 0 , 10, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: DelayedAnimation(
                   child:  
                    Text(
                            lastMenusEnd.toString(),
                     textScaleFactor : 1,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Comic',
                     color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 30,

                    ),
                    ),


                    delay: delayedAmount + 1000,
                              ),
              ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 3, 0, 10),
                    child: DelayedAnimation(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                        'This is your cycle:',
                         textScaleFactor : 1,
                        style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Comic',
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 25
                        ),
                        ),
                ),
                      delay: delayedAmount + 2000,
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
             itemCount: dates.length,
               itemBuilder: (context, index){
         return DelayedAnimation(
                    child: Container(
             margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB( 15, 0, 15, 10),
             padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
             height: 110,
             width: 160,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
             color: dates[index].color,
        ),
             child: ListTile(
               onTap: () {
                   //Shoe BreakFast, Lucnch $ Dinner for that day
                 },
                 title: Padding(
                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                   child: Text(
                     '${dates[index].dateName}',
                      textScaleFactor : 1,
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.greenAccent[400],
                       fontFamily: 'Comic',
                       fontSize: 25
                     ),
                     ),
                 ),
                 subtitle: Text(
                   'BreakFast, Lunch, Dinner',
                    textScaleFactor : 1,
                   style: TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.black87,
                     fontFamily: 'Comic',
                     fontSize: 14
                   ),
                   ),
                  //  leading: Padding(
                  //    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 0, 0),
                  //    child: CircleAvatar(
                  //    backgroundImage: AssetImage(dates[index].image),
                  //    radius: 20,
                  //  ),
                  //  ),
                  //  trailing: Padding(
                  //    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 14, 0, 9),
                  //    child: CircleAvatar(
                  //        child :  Text(
                  //      '${dates[index].dayName}',
                  //       textScaleFactor : 1,
                  //      style: TextStyle(
                  //      color: Colors.black,
                  //      fontFamily: 'Comic',
                  //      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  //      fontSize: 15
                  //    ),
                  //    ),
                  //    radius: 30,
                  //    backgroundColor: dates[index].color,
                  //    ),
                  //  ),

                  ),
           ),
           delay: delayedAmount + dates[index].delay,
           // Using this logic for the delay.. this means the listview builder would always complete 1 cycle
           // before its starts another. apply this for ads
         );
         }
             ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So I dont know how I can pass that information to this page

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code as you posted now is erroring because you are trying to use the Home class in the line `DateTime lastMenusEnd = Home.lastmenus;` without ever creating an instance of the home class. Can you post the error it gives you? Since that code does not live inside any class or method as I can see it may run but will be unuseable from within the app itself.

Also you have your Home class as a StatefulWidget, and run the createState method, but I am not seeing where you define the `_HomeState()` class. You would be able to access the lastmenus variable inside the `_HomeState()` or `Home` class itself, but doing so in the _HomeState() would require you to access `widget.lastmenus`.

Update:
You are getting a static access error since you have not created an instance of Home and are trying to access a variable on it that is not static and initialized. I think to accomplish what you want you need to create a _HomeState and move all your logic inside there.

Quick update to your code to accomplish this:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {

final DateTime lastmenus;
Home({this.lastmenus});

  @override
 _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();


}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  DateTime _currentdate = new DateTime.now();
  DateTime lastMenusEnd;

  @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
      lastMenusEnd = widget.lastmenus;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.lastmenus);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I moved the access to the lastMenusEnd to the build method since as it is not a static field you can't access it before the state is create

Comment: This is the error sir                                                                                                                       DateTime lastmenus
package:cycle/pages/homePage.dart

Instance member 'lastmenus' can't be accessed using static access.dart(static_access_to_instance_member)

Comment: I want to use the stored value there sir at outside of any class or method.. cause am using it in other variables that are also outside

Comment: Updated my post, is there a reason you can't move it *and* the other code inside a state class? It is really a bad idea to have code not tied to classes inside flutter. In the example it will run everything inside the state when you create the Home widget

Comment: Am sorry but me moving it to the class is affecting the rest ..                                                               For example here                                                                                                                             Undefined name 'dates'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dart(undefined_identifier)

Comment: i cant access vars in there in other places